# Using data type like uint64_t in cgal's exact kernel

Tags: cgal

I am beginning with CGAL. What I would like to do is to create point that coordinates are number ~ 2^51.

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel K;

typedef K::Point_2 P;

uint_64 x,y;
//init them somehow
    P sp0(x,y);
```

Then I got a long template error. Someone could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I think that I found solution. The problem was that I used exact Kernel that supports only double, switching to inexact kernel solved the problem. It was also possible to use just double. (one of the requirements was to use data type that supports intergers up to 2^48).

Comment: Please be aware that an `Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel` wont use integer coordinates, but interval arithmetic with floating points for predicates and inexact `double` arithmetic for constructions. Please remember to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you realize that changing the kernel may have other effects on your program.

Concerning your original question, if your integer values are smaller than 2^51, then they fit exactly in doubles (with 53 bit mantissa), so one simple option is to cast them to double, as in :

```
P sp0((double)x,(double)y);
```

Otherwise, the Exact_predicates_exact_construction_kernel should have its main number type be able to read your uint64 values (maybe cast them to unsigned long long if it's OK on your platform) :

```
typedef K::FT FT;

P sp0((FT)x,(FT)y);
```

Answer (score 2):

CGAL Number types are only documented to interoperate with int and double. I recently added some code so we can construct more numbers from long (required for Eigen), and your code will work in the next version of CGAL (except that you typo-ed uint64_t) on platforms where uint64_t is unsigned int or unsigned long (not windows). For long long support, since many of our number types are based on other libraries (GMP) that do not support long long themselves yet, it may have to wait a bit.